# Prevent and queue action (but only once globally) if previously called within X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always run into this problem and seem to implement a nasty looking solution.

It seems like a common design pattern to fire an action immediately, but not let that action queue up if clicked rapidly / delay firing if previously called within a timeframe. In my real world example, I have an AJAX call being made, so if I don't prevent repetitive actions the browser queues requests.

How would you implement this differently? What other options are there?

---

```
function myFunction() {
   console.log("fired");
}

var timeout = null;
$("#foo").click(function() {
    // if not previously clicked within 1 second, fire immediately
    if (!timeout) {
        myFunction(); 
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        // clicked again within 1s
        clearTimeout(timeout); // clear it - we can't have multiple timeouts
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            myFunction();
            timeout = null;
        }, 1000);
    };
});
```

Comment: Well you can make it slightly shorter by not calling `clearTimeout()` within the callback function you pass to `setTimeout()` - it doesn't do anything anyway because at that point the timeout has already happened...

Comment: @nnnnnn, that's a very good point.. Thank you for that! Anything to make this feel less fugly is appreciated. With that removed, it looks much better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, if you repeatedly click "#foo" at an interval slightly less than one second, say every 800ms, on first click it will fire the function immediately (obviously), but then it will fire the function exactly once more one second after the *last* click. That is, if you click ten times at 800ms intervals the function will fire once immediately and a second time approximately 8 seconds (800ms * 9 + 1000ms) after the first click.

I think you're better off removing the `else` case altogether, so that on click it will fire the function if it has not been called within the last second, otherwise it will do nothing with no attempt to queue another call up for later. Not only does that seem to me like a more logical way to operate, it halves the size of your function...

On the other hand, since you mentioned Ajax, rather than disabling the function based on a timer you may like to disable the function until the last Ajax request returns, i.e., use a flag similar to your `timerid` and reset it within an Ajax complete callback (noting that Ajax complete callbacks get called after success or failure of the request).

In the case of an auto-complete or auto-search function, where you want to send an Ajax request as the user types, you might want to remove the `if` case from your existing code and keep the `else` case, because for auto-complete you likely want to wait until after the user stops typing before sending the request - for that purpose I'd probably go with a shorter delay though, say 400 or 500ms.

Regarding general structure of the code, if I wanted a function to be fired a maximum of once per second I'd likely put that control into the function itself rather than in a click handler:

```
var myFunction = function() {
                    var timerid = null;
                    return function() {
                       if (timerid) return;    
                       timerid = setTimeout(function(){ timerid=null; }, 1000);

                       // actual work of the function to be done here
                       console.log("myFunction fired");
                    };
                  }();

$("#foo").click(function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

The immediately invoked anonymous function that I've added makes it uglier, but it keeps the `timerid` variable out of the global scope. If you don't like that obviously you could simply declare `timerid` in the same scope as `myFunction()` as you currently do.

This answer is getting kind of long, but if you have a lot of different functions that all need some kind of repeat control in them you could implement a single function to handle that part of it:

```
function limitRepeats(fn, delay) {
   var timerid = null;
   return function() {
      if (timerid) return;
      timerid = setTimeout(function(){ timerid = null; }, delay);
      fn();
   };
}

// myFunction1 can only be called once every 1000ms
var myFunction1 = limitRepeats(function() {
                                 console.log("fired myFunction1()");
                              }, 1000);

// myFunction2 can only be called once every 3000ms
var myFunction2 = limitRepeats(function() {
                                 console.log("fired myFunction2()");
                              }, 3000);

$("#foo").click(function() {
    myFunction1();
    myFunction2();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response! Yes it's important that the first request is instantaneous and that future requests behave more like an auto-complete plugin. The exact scenario is here: http://www.grovemade.com/product/ipad-case/ (push left or right) - I need instant response for a majority of uses but I need to prevent ajax requests from stacking up in the browser. I also need to queue the function instead of completely preventing it because it needs to load the last element selected. Thanks for the idea putting code into the ajax response, that's a great idea!